# Split string of coordinates and put it in array

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2

After doing the funtion: cirkelFeatures[1].getCoordinates().toString()
I'am receiving the coordinates of the polygon (they are in epsg 31370)

"140015.12392378994,147993.86462185346,146949.24235978903,143983.79136079177,146934.0790524634,135989.98578868713,139984.87561409094,132006.24716971722,133050.7963502835,136016.25281185843,133065.88134080853,144010.058368247,140015.12392378994,147993.86462185346"

How is it possible to push this in a array? 
I'am thinking it would be something with .split(',')
but it should split after each SECOND commma...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
var yourString = '0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0';
var string = yourString.split(',');

// Create array of float for each pair of coordinate
var a = string.length; 
for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    string[i] = parseFloat(string[i]);
}

// Initialize an array to store the new values
var b = string.length / 2;
var array = [];
for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        array[i] = [0, 0];
}

// Create an array of array of coordinates
var k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        array[i][j] = string[k];
        k++;
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

Or in ES6:

```
const chunk = (str) => {
    return  str.split(',')
        .map(parseFloat)
        .reduce((acc, val, i, arr) =>
            (i % 2) ? acc
            : [...acc, arr.slice(i, i + 2)]
        , []) 
}
const arrayOfArrays = chunk(yourString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the zip function in Python like this (not sure if this helps though since it is Python):

```
coordString = "140015.12392378994,147993.86462185346,146949.24235978903,143983.79136079177,146934.0790524634,135989.98578868713,139984.87561409094,132006.24716971722,133050.7963502835,136016.25281185843,133065.88134080853,144010.058368247,140015.12392378994,147993.86462185346"

coordList = coordString.split(',')

coords = zip(coordList,coordList[1:])[::2]
```

How about this function in Javascript

```
function coordArray(coordString) {
  var coords = coordString.split(",")
  var temp = coords.slice();
  var arr = [];

  while (temp.length) {
    arr.push(temp.splice(0,2));
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: I prefer Javascript if it's possible..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function string.split(",") in javascript it returns an array of in which you can find your coordinates as @Peter mentioned, you can also get your coordinates with

```
cirkelFeatures[1].getGeometry().getFirstCoordinates();
```

in OL 3

Comment: Thanks
Witht the information that i found here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182603/open-layers-get-coordinates-of-drawn-features

It should work